# World forest vs timber?

Tags: word-meaning

In this IELTS test, they illustrate the regions according to the percentage of **world forest** and **timber**. I suppose world forest means areas of trees not used for construction, while timber means the opposite. Correct me if I'm wrong please. Another problem is I don't know why they added **world** to **forest** but not to **timber**. I guess **world forest** means "the forest around the world", but it seems rather redundant and confusing to me instead of being informative.

[image]

Comment: As you're obviously aware, "timber" and "forest" are related but distinct terms. Why an IELTS test should seek to confuse you with this pair of charts isn't obvious to me, and it certainly seems a stupid way to test whether you *understand* the difference. But you have the full context, and we don't.

Comment: _Timber_ is trees after they have been cut down.

Comment: How can a place have more timber than forest?  Isn't timber culled from species in the forest suitable for use in construction? Or is the distinction between natural forest and tree plantation?

Comment: @TimRonsomedevice Pie #2 does not show quantities, but percentages. If N.America has higher timber % than forest %, it might cut down more than others proportionally.

Comment: @YosefBaskin  That doesn't clarify things for me.  What is "percentage of timber"? Does it include imported timber? Is it timber measured at a point in time?  I have no idea what the timber chart represents.

Comment: I read % of timber as the region's production as % of the world total.

Comment: @FumbleFingers this is also my whole context.

What about _forest_? Could you tell me why it is _world forest_ instead of just _forest_? Is it important to include it? Can I just ignore the word _world_ when reporting the main features of the charts?

Comment: I can't answer that. I have no idea what kind of response whoever wrote this moronic "test" is looking for. If the test somehow relates to preceding course-work, perhaps there are clues there. Feasibly, "world timber" implies timber sold on the international market, I dunno. Nor do I know if, for example, pinewood counts as "timber" if it's only being grown for immediate pulping into toilet paper.

Comment: @YosefBaskin: I wouldn't count it as "timber" while it's still growing. In which case assigning "percentage of world timber" to different countries / regions implies assigning potentially misleadingly high values to area that specialize in growing "quick turnaround" fast-growing softwoods. Probably assisted by western government subsidies designed to replace other countries' rainforests with our own pine forests!

Comment: Maybr the implication of the charts is that Europeans buy wooden furniture made in other countries, rather than use the wood from cutting down our own trees! Or we just don't use timber so much in general. Who knows?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I did not count timber that is growing.